# how to create separate contextual filters for pages in views

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view and it has a block and two pages say page1 and page2. If I set the contextual filter it applies for both page1 and page2. I have configured two contextual filters and I want first contextual filter to be applied for page1 and other for page2. Is it possible to do so? If not is there any alternative where I can have separate contextual filters for separate pages.

While filtering a views page it should evaluate only one contextual filter. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting everything the way you want it on the first page, switch to the other display and change those settings, but for each one make sure you have the `This page (override)` drop-down selected.

Comment: thanks, are you telling me to change the settings of existing contextual filter i.e. the contextual filter for page1, then I cannot do that. I need both the filters. And I have tried your way, added the second contextual filter with page override but its not working.

Comment: sorry mate. its working. i followed your way and just rearranged the contextual filter and its working fine. thanks a lot